# Why map doesn't work on new Array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does the code bellow returns an array of undefined values and I don't see any logs?

```
var arr = new Array(10);
arr = arr.map(function () {
    console.log('kapa');
    return 1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Array.apply

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function(){return 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the ECMAScript specification and the slightly more readable MDN description of `.map()` spell it out fairly clearly.  The `.map()` callback is not called for empty values of the array (e.g. values that are `undefined`).

From the MDN description for `.map()`:

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
>   array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback
>   is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values;
>   it is not invoked for indexes that are undefined, those which have
>   been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

So, since `var arr = new Array(10);` creates an array with ten empty slots in it, there are no values in the array that `.map()` will call its callback for.

If you actually put values in the initial array, then you will see the desired result:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr = arr.map(function() {
    return 1;
});
console.log(arr);    // [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9c0hmL2j/

---

For some further documentation on `.map()`, you can see the [ECMAScript specification for `Array.prototype.map`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19).  Steps 8b and 8c in that section of the spec describe how the callback to `.map()` will not be called if a given array property has no value.

Answer (score -1):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

You don't have elements if you call new Array[10]

You must do something like

```
var temp = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    temp[i]=i;
}
```

Or in your case

```
var temp = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    temp.push(i);
}
```